# Which Event comes first Activate or Open?

Tags: vba, ms-project

In VBA for MS-Project, what code is ran first, the `project_activate` or `project_open`?

Comment: you can add code to both function, and add difeerent `MsgBox`,then when you run it, you can see which `MsgBox` comed first

Comment: How are you going to Activate a Project before it is Opened?

Comment: Makes sense @ThomasInzina. I've tested Shai Rado suggestion and it confirmed your statement. Cheers

Comment: When you can you should post your answer an close the question.  I think that `Which Event comes first Activate or Open ` is a better title.  :)

Answer (score 1):

As said in the coments it wouldn't make sense to activate a project that isn't open. It can be tested with simple msgboxes. That said, the `open` event comes before the `activate`